# Definition of the autocorrelation in Time series

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, definition, time-series

The standard definition of the autocorrelation of a random variable X(t) is $$R_X(s,t)=\frac{\mathbb{E}[(X(s)-\mu_s)(X(t)-\mu_t)]}{\sigma_s\sigma_t}$$

I'm currently analyzing time series theory, particularly when I have that X(t) is a WSS (wide-sense stationary) process. Therefore, the mean $\mu$ and the variance $\sigma^2$ are time independent, so one can easily show that the autocorrelation only depends on the lag $\tau=s-t$, and now we have that $$R_X(\tau)=\frac{\mathbb{E}[(X_{t+\tau}-\mu)(X_t-\mu)]}{\sigma^2}$$

I have some questions about this. First of all, what would the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ mean here? Their integral (in the classical way) isn't necessarily well defined because X(t) is a WSS process and therefore it doesn't necessarily tend to zero for large values of $t$.

Also, I have seen in several sites another "equivalent" definition of the autocorrelation by simply ignoring the $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ parameters from the equation and defining it as $$R_X(\tau)=\mathbb{E}[X_{t+\tau}X_t]$$ Where this latter definition is used to easily define the Power Spectral Density (PSD) function. In which way could you say that this two definitions are "equivalent"? What are the advantages of using one instead the other?

Thank you very much.

Comment: $\mu_t = \mathbb{E}(X_t)$ and $\sigma^2_t = \mathbb{E}((X_t-\mu)^2)$. When $X_t$ is  stationary (mean and variance and correlation not depending on $t$) you can  consider instead $\mathbb{E}[X_t X_{t+\tau}]$. Note how this property stays true when filtering $Y_t = h \ast X_t$

Comment: @user1952009 again, I would like to know why does $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ still makes sense, as that function isn't really integrable. Same for variance. What does $Y_t$ and $h$ mean in the last line?

Comment: Of course we assume the 2nd moment exist so that the mean and variance are well-defined

Comment: But in Time Series, $X(t)$ may have infinite energy, so how can we calculate $\mu$? Also, I still don't understand why the mean and variance terms can be ommited

Comment: No, $X_t$ is a single random variable and we require it has a finite mean and variance. $\mu_t = \mathbb{E}[X_t],\sigma_t^2 = \mathbb{E}[(X_t-mu)^2]$. Only after that, we take a look at $X_\tau$ for the other values of $\tau$, and if $X_\tau$ is stationary for the two 1st moments : that is $\mu_\tau = \mu, \sigma_\tau^2 = \sigma^2$.